nested css declaration with pseudo classes in svg style tag not working
I have and SVg and adding  tag inside svg and using nested css delcration syntax and wehn using & it gives error of some XMl error ;
first see this html example


<style type="text/css">
  :root {
    --color-red: #FF5733;
  }

  div {
    background-color: yellow;
    .card {
    border: 2px solid grey;
      height:2rem;
      width:2rem;
      margin: 1rem;
        background-color: var(--color-red);
        &:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: blue;
        }
      }
  }

  </style>

  <div>

    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>

  </div>
<section>
<p>Working SVG but not applying pseudo-class</p>
<svg width="600" height="90" viewBox="0 0 600 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="card" x="42" y="50" width="16" height="16" />
  <rect class="card" x="120" y="20" width="16" height="16" />
  <style type="text/css">
:root {
--color-red: #FF5733;
}
rect {
.card {
fill: var(--color-red);
:nth-child(odd) {
fill: blue;
}
  }

  }   
</style>
</svg>
</section>
<section>
<p> works when nested under svg `&` does not works </p>
<svg width="600" height="90" viewBox="0 0 600 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="card" x="42" y="50" width="16" height="16" />
  <rect class="card" x="120" y="20" width="16" height="16" />
<style type="text/css">
:root {
--color-red: #FF5733;
}
svg {
.card {
fill: var(--color-red);
}
:nth-child(odd) {
fill: blue;
}
}
</style>
</svg>
</section>



which works and if we remove & ahead to :nth-child then does not work as expected;
now same thing trying in svg ( and my requirement is every odd rectacle will be blue and otherwise red  ( note: background-color replace by fill )
<svg width="600" height="90" viewBox="0 0 600 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="card" x="42" y="50" width="16" height="16" />
  <rect class="card" x="120" y="20" width="16" height="16" />
  <style type="text/css">
    :root {
    --color-red: #FF5733;
    }
    svg {
    .card {
    fill: var(--color-red);
    :nth-child(odd) {
    fill: blue;
    }
    }

    }
  </style>
</svg>

in above :nth-child does not work nor  &:nth-child
although changing the navigation, then it works
<svg width="600" height="90" viewBox="0 0 600 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect class="card" x="42" y="50" width="16" height="16" />
  <rect class="card" x="120" y="20" width="16" height="16" />
<style type="text/css">
    :root {
    --color-red: #FF5733;
    }
    rect {
    .card {
    fill: var(--color-red);
    }
    :nth-child(odd) {
    fill: blue;
    }
    }
</style>
</svg>

but then adding & ahead to nth-child, it does not work and show nothing in browser
so my question is

does css nesting does not work proper in svg style tag
why does adding nth-child selector on parent svg works but not on .card


intrestingly it works in SO code spinnet but not in browser

If it works in the StackSnippet that suggests a specificity issue with other CSS.

tried in chrome an fireforx with no other file, but same result

Yes but in that case it doesn't work as desired

"...although changing the navigation, then it works..." What do you mean by saying, "changing navigation"?

my bad, changing navigation means the css nesting declaration, updated the code ( previoulsy both code snippet was same)

question is closed? on what basis

While I don't agree with the closing reason – I tend to agree with the closing itself as it's based on a simple CSS error.  1. CSS doesn't work as .card selects the <rect> elements which don't have any children – so :nth-child(odd) won't select anything. 2. example doesn't work because .card is applied to the rect elements – so the nesting doesn't make much sense and as before we don't have an nth child of <rect>. No specific behavior related to SVG elements selected by pseudo-class selectors. See codepen example

Despite the fact this post may not be very helpful as it doesn't describe a SVG specific CSS issues, I vote to reopen this question to give it a fair chance

The  Ampersand is Key
The  is a placeholder for the nested selector's parent selector. I've seen comments about how the  is optional for nested CSS, and while that's true what's not mentioned is the fact that when the CSS is parsed that  and a space is added to all nested selectors. So if you neglect to add a , a  and a space will be added. Review the code block below to see the difference this makes. Assume that there are 3 .child within .parent.
Example 1
/**
 *
 * The & is .child
 * The space after the & means that what next is a descendant
 *
 *   Flattened Selector
 *   .parent .child :nth-child
 *
 * This selector points to nothing .child doesn't have any
 * descendants.
 */
.parent {
  .child {
    background: gold;
    & :nth-child(odd) {
      background: cyan;
    }
  }
}

In the following Demos are the HTML is identical:
Example 2
  <svg id="A to D">
    <polygon class="shape">
    <circle class="shape">
    <rect class="shape">
  </svg>


Demo 1

2 levels of nested selectors

.shape in <svg>, :nth-child(odd) in .shape




Demo 2

1 level of nested selectors

.shape and :nth-child(odd) are direct descendants of <svg>





Demo 1


:root {
  font: 10px/1 "Palatino Linotype"
}

#area1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 50%, navy 50%);
}

.id {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
}

/**
 * Flattened Selector
 * #A .shape:nth-child(odd) ⭐
 * CORRECT
 * Prefixing &:nth-child is .shape:nth-child
 */
#A {
  .shape {
    fill: gold;

    &:nth-child(odd) {
      fill: cyan;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Flattened Selector
 * #B .shape :nth-child 
 * INCORRECT
 * Missing & defaults to & + space
 */
#B {
  .shape {
    fill: gold;

    :nth-child(odd) {
      fill: cyan;
    }
  }
}
<svg id="area1" width="420" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <text class="id" width="30" width="30" x="150" y="40">#A</text>
    
  <svg id="A" width="210" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     
    <polygon class="shape" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" transform="scale(0.3)"/>
  
    <circle class="shape" r="25" cx="100" cy="70"/> 
  
    <rect class="shape" width="50" height="50" x="150" y="90"/>

  </svg>

  <text class="id" width="30" width="30" x="360" y="40">#B</text>

  <svg id="B" width="210" height="150" x="210" y="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <polygon class="shape" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" transform="scale(0.3)"/>
  
    <circle class="shape" r="25" cx="100" cy="70"/> 
  
    <rect class="shape" width="50" height="50" x="150" y="90"/>

  </svg>

</svg>



Demo 2


:root {
  font: 10px/1 "Palatino Linotype"
}

#area2 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 50%, navy 50%);
}

.id {
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
}

/**
 * Flattened Selector
 * #C:nth-child(odd) 
 * INCORRECT
 * #C is parent to both .shape and :nth-child
 */
#C {
  .shape {
    fill: gold;
  }

  &:nth-child(odd) {
    fill: cyan;
  }
}

/**
 * Flattened Selector
 * #D .shape:nth-child(odd) ⭐
 * CORRECT
 * Both .shape and :nth-child are children of #D
 */
#D {
  .shape {
    fill: gold;
  }
  
  :nth-child(odd) {
    fill: cyan;
  }
}
<svg id="area2" width="420" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <text class="id" width="30" width="30" x="150" y="40">#C</text>
    
  <svg id="C" width="210" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     
    <polygon class="shape" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" transform="scale(0.3)"/>
  
    <circle class="shape" r="25" cx="100" cy="70"/> 
  
    <rect class="shape" width="50" height="50" x="150" y="90"/>

  </svg>

<text class="id" width="30" width="30" x="360" y="40">#D</text>

<svg id="D" width="210" height="150" x="210" y="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <polygon class="shape" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" transform="scale(0.3)"/>
  
    <circle class="shape" r="25" cx="100" cy="70"/> 
  
    <rect class="shape" width="50" height="50" x="150" y="90"/>

  </svg>

</svg>




<style> inside a SVG is not scoped.
Cleaning up your long code.
The second style styles the whole page:


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10">
  <rect x="0"  width="10" height="10" />
  <rect x="10" width="10" height="10" />
  <rect x="20" width="10" height="10" />
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
      rect {
        fill: red;
        &:nth-child(odd) {
          fill: green;
        }
      }
    }   
  </style>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 10">
  <rect x="0"  width="10" height="10" />
  <rect x="10" width="10" height="10" />
  <rect x="20" width="10" height="10" />
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
      rect {
        fill: rebeccapurple;
        &:nth-child(odd) {
          fill: hotpink;
        }
      }
    }   
  </style>
</svg>




Thanks but did not underdtand what is wrong in my code? written <style>  before closing  </svg> just like your code shows

tried your code in chrome latest in mac and other browsers like edge and brave; all gives error, see screeshot here https://imgur.com/a/Yao7GpF
